# Cannot call blockUI function from asp button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-blockui

First of all it does work as a regular button:

```
<input type="button" value="Block" id="btnBlock" name="btnBlock"/>
```

But I need to work on an asp:button as well, I've tried this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBlock" runat="server" Text="Block" OnClientClick="btnClick"/>
```

But it doesn't work, just sends a JS error (edited):

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'btnBlock' is undefined

My JS blockUI function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btnBlock').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#myForm') });
    });
});
</script>
```

I've also tried changing the blockUI function to this, but it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't recognize the asp code inside the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#<%= btnBlock.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#myForm') });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is there because your error says 'btnClick' is undefined, not 'btnBlock' is undefined.  Also, if the last didn't work, it should say 'ct100_clientplaceholder_btnBlock is undefined' (something like that).

Comment: Sorry I was trying with different functions at the time, I changed it back to btnBlock and still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your asp button markup you've got

```
OnClientClick="btnClick"
```

This sets the client-side script that executes when a Button control's Click event is raised. That is the fired event looks for a javascript function called btnClick. The issue is that you are wiring the click event via jQuery $(selector).click(someFunction); and also in the OnClientClick event.

Change the asp button control to remove the OnClientClick event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBlock" runat="server" Text="Block" />
```

Keeping the javascript the same.